# if that tests on strings input from the command line

Tags: haskell

How to write an if function and condition it on a char?

Like I am writing this function:

```
import System.IO

start::Char->IO()String
start s =
  if s == 'instructions'
    then instructions
  else
    putStrLn "Look"

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter"
  n <- readLn :: Char
  start n
```

which takes an input from the user, like "instructions" or somethhing, then I call the start function with it and from there call the instructions function.
What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you want to compare to a `Char` or a `String`? A `Char` is a single character while a `String` is a list of characters. If you want to compare to `"instructions"` then you need to use a `String`.

Comment: Remark: `if cond **then** expr else expr`

Comment: I want to type "instructions" in the command line and then it should go into the if condition when the character entered is "instructions".

Comment: (Sorry I deleted the comment that was in response to). And then what would `instructions` do?

Comment: It would print the instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Char` is a single character, while a `String` is a list of characters i.e. `[Char]`. If you want to compare the argument to `start` with `"instructions"` you will need to make it a `String` and enclose `instructions` in double quotes.

The syntax for `if` expressions are `if condition then e1 else e2` so you need to add a `then` before `instructions`.

You probably want to use `getLine` instead of `readLn` to get a `String` from the console.

```
instructions :: IO ()
instruction = ...

start :: String -> IO ()
start s = 
  if s == "instructions"
    then instructions
  else
    putStrLn "Look"

main = do
  putStrLn "Enter"
  n <- getLine
  start n
```

Answer (score 2):

The main points:

- Firstly it looks like you're thinking that `Char` is the same thing as a multi-character string. It's not, a `Char` is only a single character, and so can never equal to `"instructions"` (and I think the compiler would spot that). So you should use `String` in most cases when you're expecting anything that could be more than one character long. `String` is essentially the same thing as `[Char]`, which is an array of single characters.
- Secondly, literal `String`s in Haskell need to be surrounded by double quotes, so it should be `"instructions"`
- Thirdly, the type of `readLn` would need to be `IO String` and not just `String`
- Fourthly, I would use `getLine` instead of `readLn`, as `readLn` would require the user to enter quotes for strings: the user would have to type `"instructions"` including the double quotes, which I suspect is not what you're after

Putting all that together, with a dummy implementation of `instructions`

```
import System.IO

instructions :: IO()
instructions = putStrLn "Some instructions"

start:: String -> IO()
start s = if s == "instructions"
          then
            instructions
          else
            putStrLn "Look"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter"
  n <- getLine :: IO String
  start n
```

Comment: Could I ask one more small thing here? That is: how to return more than one value from a function? Like a simple function, that takes a string and returns two strings. How to do that?

Comment: @linda That sounds like a completely different question, so I think it better if you ask it as such, rather than in the comments of another.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to learn the difference between a string and a character. This is a very fundamental concept to computer programming. In Haskell (and many other languages), single quotes indicate a character and double quotes indicate a String. In other words, change

```
if s == 'instructions'
```

to

```
if s == "instructions"
```

Also, change

```
start::Char->IO()String
```

to

```
start :: String -> IO()
```